# Database data doesn't show on HTML page

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have created a database in Visual Studio and I try to run it on localhost HTML page, but it's not showing. All the page shows is the plain HTML text, so the page is working, but for some reason it can't see my database.

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Gats] (
    [GatsId] INT           NOT NULL,
    [Nom]    NVARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
    [Sexe]   NVARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
    [Edat]   NVARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([GatsId] ASC)
);
```

HomeController:

```
namespace ShelterManager.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult GetGats()
        {
            using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var gats = dc.Gats;
                return Json(new { data = gats }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>GatsManager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:90%; margin: 0 auto">
        <table id="MyDatabase">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nom</th>
                    <th>Sexe</th>
                    <th>Edat</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var oTable = $('#MyDatatable').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url" : '/home/GetGats',
                    "type" : "get",
                    "datatype" : "json"
                },
                "columns" : [
                    {"data" : "Nom", "autoWidth": true },
                    {"data": "Sexe", "autoWidth": true },
                    {"data": "Edat", "autoWidth": true },
                ]
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `MyDatabaseEntities`? An entity framework `DbContext`? Also, what is the value of `var gats = dc.Gats;` in the Controller? Can you please set a breakpoint there?

Comment: I created a Model, which then EF Designer from Database, then I chose MyDatabase and below I checked Save connection setting in Web.Config as: MyDatabaseEntities. My db table and other folders are all inside MyDatabaseEntities. Also this was a default name, but I could have changed it to anything I wanted

Comment: Gats is the name of my db table.

Comment: Are you sure there's actually rows in that table to return? This is all pretty basic stuff, so it would behoove you to spend some time with the tutorials: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/models-data. Also, be advised that Model First and Database First have been deprecated. If you don't want to have to gut your app later, you should use Code First (which despite the name, can work with existing databases just as well as create new ones).

Comment: Yeah I should do that, thanks man!